# Prove $\frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta} \equiv \csc\theta + \cot\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

This must be proved using elementary trigonometric identities.

I have not been able to come to any point which seems useful enough to include in this post.

Comment: Hint: Can you make the denominator $\sin^2 \theta$ in some way?

Comment: Multiply by $\sin(\theta)(1-\cos(\theta))$ and simplify.

Comment: @M.Vinay I finally understand what you meant by that :)

Comment: @Midni Glad you did. Another way you could've done this is start from the RHS $\csc \theta + \cot \theta$ by rewriting it as $\dfrac{1}{\sin \theta} + \dfrac{\cos \theta}{\sin \theta} = \dfrac{1 + \cos \theta}{\sin \theta}$, noting that this is somewhat similar to the LHS, and finding out how one can be transformed into the other.

Comment: Or, after getting the RHS into that form, you could equate the LHS and RHS (just to see what happens if they are indeed equal as you're trying to prove), then cross-multiplying to get $\sin^2 \theta = 1 - \cos^2 \theta$, which is a well known identity. You can reverse engineer this to get the proof.

Comment: @M.Vinay For the sake of getting a better understanding, I did like you mention with the RHS. I'm feeling more confident now. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiply the LHS by $1+\cos\theta$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\cdot\frac{1+\cos\theta}{1+\cos\theta}&=\frac{\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)}{1-\cos^2\theta}\\
&=\frac{\sin\theta(1+\cos\theta)}{\sin^2\theta}\qquad;\qquad\color{red}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1}\\
&=\frac{1+\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}+\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}\\
&=\color{blue}{\csc\theta+\cot\theta}.\qquad\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}

Comment: Great stuff! What is that called, multiplying by that?

Comment: Multiplying by the conjugate?

Comment: @Midni Yup! Multiplying by its conjugate. Actually, the reason behind this is to obtain $\sin^2\theta$ so we can simplify the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Okay okay, seeing it in that light is slightly more comforting. I was looking at it purely as 'just multiplying by the conjugate solved this', which at first almost sounded trivial to me. But now I'm a better person haha. Thank you

Comment: @Midni You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Lets get rid of the trigonometry stuff first:

$$s=\sin(\theta),~~c=\cos(\theta),~~\csc(\theta)=\frac{1}{s},~~\cot(\theta)=\frac{c}{s}$$

Now we are solving this equation:

$$\frac{s}{1-c}=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{c}{s}$$

$$\Leftrightarrow$$

$$\frac{s}{1-c}-\frac{1}{s}-\frac{c}{s}=0$$

multiply by $(1-c)\neq 0$

$$s-\frac{1-c}{s}-\frac{(1-c)c}{s}=0$$

multiply by $s\neq 0$

$$s^2-(1-c)-(1-c)c = s^2-1+c-c+c^2 =0\Leftrightarrow s^2+c^2=1$$

The only solutions to this algebraic equation are $s=\sin(\theta)$ and $c=\cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Wow, I love seeing this in a different light. This is really nice. I hope to remember trying to think like this in the future.

Comment: @Peter I think you can make it quite a bit shorter by writing $\dfrac{1}{s} + \dfrac{c}{s} = \dfrac{1 + c}{s}$ right after the first step, then taking the $s$ in the denominator to the left side and the $1 - c$ in the denominator of the left side to the right side to get $(1 - c)(1 + c) = 1 - c^2$.